# Seaborn displaying one barplot instead of multiple plots

Tags: python, seaborn

My code looks like

```
ylst = [.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8]
xlst=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
with PdfPages('probs.pdf') as pdf_pages:
    for i in range(0,len(xlst), 2):
        ax=sns.barplot(xlst[i:i+2], ylst[i:i+2])
        ax.axes.set_title('Which name', fontsize=24,color="b",alpha=0.3)
        ax.set_ylabel("Probability (%)",size = 17,color="r",alpha=0.5)

        for p in ax.patches:
            ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))
        pdf_pages.savefig()
```

I want to 4 plots, in a 2 row by 2 column matrix. That is, the upper left plot should show `A` and `B` with values .1 and .2. Then, the lower left or upper right plot should show `C` and `D` with values .3 and .4. And so on

However, what I instead get is:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested that this works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

ylst = [.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8]
xlst=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
with PdfPages('probs.pdf') as pdf_pages:
    fig,((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2)
    list_of_axes = (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4)
    for i,j in zip(range(0,len(xlst), 2),list_of_axes):
        sns.barplot(xlst[i:i+2], ylst[i:i+2],ax=j)
        j.axes.set_title('Which name', fontsize=24,color="b",alpha=0.3)
        j.set_ylabel("Probability (%)",size = 17,color="r",alpha=0.5)

        for p in j.patches:
            j.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))
    pdf_pages.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

I've just assigned an axis for each subplot and moved `.savefig()` outside of the loop.